# Variavel global para armazenamento de diretórios em Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Boa tarde Pessoal,

estou criando um programa em python usando a GUI tkinter que utilizam varias telas e na configuração da GUI eu preciso chamar alguns arquivos de texto e imagem.
Gostaria da ajuda dos senhores para encontrar uma forma de usar uma variável onde eu possa guardar o caminho do diretório da venv que ficam imagens e arquivos de texto facilitando a chamada destes arquivos.

segue um exemplo abaixo de como estou usando, porem preciso criar a variável em cada tela do programa para que a variável funcione.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font  as tkfont

dir_venv = 'C:\\Users\cs305672\\PycharmProjects\\SACER\\venv'

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        imagem = tk.PhotoImage(file=dir_venv+'\\img\\logo_xxx.PNG')
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Bem vindo ao sistema de configuração de equipamentos de rede",
                     font=controller.title_font)
        label_logo = tk.Label( self, image=imagem)
        label_logo.imagem = imagem
        label_logo.pack( side='top', padx=10, pady=10 )
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        lf1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Escolha a marca do equipamento ou serviço que deseja acessar:",
                        font=("Arial", 15, "bold"), bd=5)
        button1 = tk.Button(lf1, text="Cisco", width=15,height=3,font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'),
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("TelaCisco"))
        button2 = tk.Button(lf1, text="Orbit", width=15,height=3, font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'),
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("TelaOrbit"))
        button3 = tk.Button( lf1, text="Raisecom",width=15,height=3, font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'),
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame("TelaRaisecom"))
        button4 = tk.Button( lf1, text="Fibra", width=15, height=3, font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'),
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame("TelaFibra"))

        button1.pack(side='top', fill='x', padx=10, pady=7)
        button2.pack(side='top', fill='x', padx=10, pady=7)
        button3.pack(side='top', fill='x', padx=10, pady=7)
        button4.pack(side='top', fill='x', padx=10, pady=7)

         lf1.pack(side='left', fill='both', padx=50, pady=50, ipadx=700, ipady=500 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variáveis em um módulo,assim como funções e classes, podem ser importadas em Python.

Então, se o seu projeto tem uma arquivo "config.py" que tem uma variável "data_path", em qualquer lugar que você quiser usar a mesma, é só fazer:

```
from meu_projeto.config import data_path
```

Agora - se o seu projeto não está devidamente configurado como um pacote de Python no ambiente atual, essa linha vai falhar,por que o Python não entende o que é "meu_projeto". Para isso funcionar você tem que ter a pasta onde está essa pasta "meu_projeto" dentro do PYTHONPATH - (se for o diretório de trabalho de onde o Python é chamado, já funciona) - mas preferenciamente seu projeto tem que ser instalável no virtualenv.

Para isso, basta ter um arquivo mínimo de `setup.py` que você pode enriquecer conforme o projeto usar mais recursos.

Esse arquivo só precisa ter uma chamada ao `setuptools.setup` passando a pasta onde estão os seus arquivos (até o nome do projeto ele "adivinha"):

￼

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='meu_projeto',
    packages=find_packages(),    
)
```

(Depois veja a documenação de como melhorar esse arquivo - https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/ )

Tendo esse arquivo no lugar, você deve instalar o seu pacote para desenvolvimento no ambiente virtual em que ele vai ser executado. Você está usando o pycharm, e o pycharm tenta abstrair o "ambiente virtual" e criar tudo sozinho, isso encurta alguns passos, mas as pessoas desaprendem, ou pior, **nunca chegam a aprender** o fundamento desses ambientes compartientados do Python.

De qualquer forma, com o ambiente virtual do projeto ativo, na pasta onde está o setup.py digite `python setup.py develop`, ou `pip install -e .`

E por fim, do jeito que você esta fazendo, vai funcionar o seu programa - desde que você esteja no seu computador, e rodando ele por dentro do pycharm. :-) Já que o caminho para o ambiente virtual está hard-coded dentro do código - uma péssima ideia: qualquer um que vá rodar o seu programa teria que editar essa variável.

Um arquivo Python sempre sabe em que pasta está: a variável `__file__` existe em cada módulo em execução de Python e tem o caminho completo para o arquivo.

Se for desejado o caminho do virtualenv, também é possível  - a variável `sys.executable` aponta para o Python do virtualenv que está sendo usado.

Por sua vez, a classe `pathlib.Path` facilita, entre outras coisas, obter o diretório que contém um arquivo, usando o atributo ".parent" (dessa forma se evita ginásticas como `__file__.rsplit("/", 1)[0]`).

Em sua, no arquivo que você escolher deixar essas configurações que quiser compartilhar com os outros arquivos:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

dir_venv = Path(sys.executable).parent.parent
```

E, reiterando, depois, nos outros arquivos é só fazer  `from meu_projeto.config import dir_venv`

Answer (score -1):

Tenta chamar a variável ao interno de cada função menos onde você declarou pela primeira vez

```
global dir_env
```